Customize Ubuntu for 3440 x 1440 resolution monitor
I'm running Ubuntu 24.04 on my Dell server, maximum resolution available is 1920 x 1080, which is kind of distorted display on my Acer 34" monitor.
I tried all the suggested solutions in open source community, but I still had no luck. Can anyone guide me on how to set right resolution?
System Details Report
Report details:

Date generated:                              2024-11-05 15:42:47

Hardware Information:

Hardware model:                              Dell Inc. Precision 5820 Tower X-Series
Memory:                                      16.0 GiB
Processor:                                   Intel Core i9-10900X × 20
Graphics:                                    AMD Radeon Pro WX 2100
Disk capacity:                               4.3 TB

Software Information:

Firmware version:                            2.38.0
OS name:                                     Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS
OS build:                                    (null)
OS type:                                     64-bit
GNOME version:                               46
Windowing system:                            Wayland
Kernel version:                              Linux 6.8.0-48-generic---


What driver are you using?  If you aren't using the proprietary drivers for AMD you might not be able to use all the potential display resolutions.  Additionally, if the AMD card doesn't support that resolution you might be stuck with only what resolutions are in use on your environment/hardware
